# NP Hardness boundary

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have two problems.

> 1. Is there a clique of size k in a graph? NP Hard
> 2. Is there a clique of size 50 in a graph? - Can be found out 
>            in polynomial time O(n^50)

Why is the second problem not NP hard where as the first one is?

EDIT: Assuming P!=NP

Comment: It may well be NP hard (if P = NP).

Comment: cstheory question? And don't use code block for a quote - it gets hard to read ;). As far as the question itself goes, I think it's because 50 is a constant, where k is not so we can't lower any bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is NP-hard because an arbitrary NP-complete problem (say, 3-SAT) can be reduced to it in polynomial time. (by the definition of NP-hardness)

The second problem is not NP-hard, because an arbitrary NP-complete problem cannot be reduced to it (say, 3-SAT, with >50 clauses).

In fact, the second problem is in P, because `O(n^50)` belongs to P. But that isn't the reason why it is not NP-hard (specifically, NP *doesn't* mean non-polynomial).

Answer (score 4):

`n^k` is exponential whereas `n^50` is polynomial.